# LUIS Speech OnIntent event does not fire (projectoxford.ai)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, speech, azure-language-understanding

Getting the SpeechIntent from voice never works (Even in given source code).  How to reproduce - Steps.

1. In ProjectOxford.ai sample programs, download the "SpeechToText-WPF-Sample".
2. In www.projectoxford.ai, login with your Hotmail id and get key1/key2 in the accounts page for Speech API.  Place the Key1 in the source code primary key at app.config.
3. Go to www.luis.ai website, login with same Hotmail id and create an App ID.  Train and create few Intents and Entities. Publish the training and you'll see a new URL to test which has another subscription id.  Copy that subscription ID (After testing your intents/entities) into your program\app.config\LUISSubscriptionID
4. Run the program with "Use Wav file and intent detection" option selected.  You may have to put right short WAV file in the appropriate folder with copy to destination property ON.

Issue:  Now the OnIntent event in the source code never fires.  If you add code to call the same url given in www.luis.ai during training, it will always tell 401-unauthorized error.

Comment: If I use URL https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/{myAppGuid}/actions?{urlencodedstring|} along with webrequest added with headers of Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key, there is no error.  However the returned value is Null "[]" in the webresponse stream.  In the debug or from projectoxford test console I get the below error.    "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Readable action object cannot be null"
  }